# Notifications appear twice

Tags: bug, android-app, notifications

I have the problem with the Android app that every notification I get from Stack  Exchange appears *twice*. For example when I am mentioned in a comment, I get two identical notifications from the Android client.

I already tried logging out and back in again, and I also tried reinstalling it from scratch. The problem persists though. On desktop, each notification is (of course) only showed once.

Just as a proof, here is a screenshot of the notification area after receiving a comment to this very question:

[image: Notification screenshot]

As you can see, it’s only a single entry in the notification area but has two messages. So it definitely comes from a single app (and I don’t have multiple versions installed anyway).

Comment: Any chance you have both the beta and production apps installed? This would explain what you describe. (happened to me in iOS app)

Comment: Weird. Another idea: on desktop computer, in your profile page, click "my logins". How many lines you see there?

Comment: Hmm… I have two there, Stack Exchange and Google, which both have the same email address and the same “last used” value. I only login using Google though.

Comment: So you might be logged in with both in the app, hence two notifications.